# How to make cargo automatically install the dependencies with version suits with a desired rustc?

Tags: build, version, rust-cargo

I need to build this https://github.com/yaoxin1995/Trusted_Client/tree/main
using Rust version 1.65 nightly. However, it keeps notifying error about the version of dependencies, and dependencies of those dependencies. This consumes a significant amount of time when attempting to specify versions for each package individually.

```
error: package `clap_builder v4.5.2` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.74 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.65.0-nightly
Either upgrade to rustc 1.74 or newer, or use
cargo update -p clap_builder@4.5.2 --precise ver
where `ver` is the latest version of `clap_builder` supporting rustc 1.65.0-nightly
```

I must adhere to rustc 1.65.0-nightly because I need to deploy QuarkContainer which only supports this specific version of rust.
So How to `cargo build`  automaticallyinstall the dependencies with version suits with current rustc?